# Add employer ratings and reviews

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I think that it would be useful to add company profiles with ability for users to rate and review them (especially useful given that *some companies* on Jobs look very shady).

Comment: Like Glassdoor?

Comment: @NSNoob, all the Jobs site is like Monster, isn't it?

Comment: To me this feels out of the scope of SO

Comment: @Danra, not more so than the Jobs site itself. And if it was decided to add Jobs to SO, then it's better to do it properly.

Comment: Hasn't this been discussed already in the case of Crossover? That rating thing can not be as useful for employers as votes are for users. People can gang-review (good or bad). SO requires us to do research before asking questions. Why should we not do that before accepting or considering job offers?

Comment: @NSNoob, this feature is for employees - not employers. "People can gang-review (good or bad)." - congrats, you've just proven the all SE can't work.

Comment: @user626528 I understand that. And not at all, I am just still trying to figure out how do you propose SO keep record of whether the rating is legit or not? (My vote is currently withheld). Do we let people rate the reviews to sort out the good ones from bad ones? How do we know that the review is genuine and is based on a genuine experience?

Comment: @user626528 Jobs makes sense in SO because there is great added value here: employers and employees can match according to the employee's skills which are proven by his answers, questions and comments, and not just stated as in a regular CV. Not every job-related feature has similar added value in SO; I think the one you're suggesting doesn't have one.

Comment: @Danra, I think that the situation where employers can see your rating and you can't see theirs is not fair and gives a lot of space for abuse from employers side.

Comment: @NSNoob, I don't see any unsolvable problems there. The question is - how useful is it?

Comment: It should be limited to only employers and employees that fulfilled a job relationship. And bidirectional rating.

Comment: @user626528 Not against rating employers in general - I just don't see what added value SO has to host this feature, vs. other employer rating sites.